# How to prove Angular that a class is Angular decored?

Tags: angular, migration

I just upgraded my app from Angular 8 to Angular 9. In this version (9), a class that use Angular features must have an appropriate Angular decorator. However, I have a component that is a `@Component({...})`. But where I run `ng serve`, it tells me that:

```
The class 'MyComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'MyModule',
but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe.
Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.
```

I am looking for a way to tell Angular that my component is already a Angular component.

My module:

```js
...
import { MyComponent } from './my-component/my-component.component';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...,
    MyComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    MyModuleRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [...]
})
export class AnnuaireModule { }
```

My Component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-emmenagement-modale',
  templateUrl: './emmenagement-modale.component.html'
})
export class EmmenagementModaleComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
}
```

Comment: See if this comment helps: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36199#issuecomment-603881000

Comment: @MichaelD no, it don't.

Comment: Can you post your component and module?

Comment: can you check the imports of component `import { Component} from '@angular/core'` and also the import of the component in the `AnnuaireModule`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the fact that `ng update @angular/cli@^9 @angular/core@^9` let me with badly compilated modules. I delete `node_modules` and then `npm i` to have clean angular modules.